# Monitoring a non-default mailbox

Tags: python, outlook

I have some code that monitors an inbox, and outputs the subject line every time a new email is recieved. For reference, I am using Outlook. The issue is that it only monitors my default inbox. Does anyone know how to get it to monitor other inboxes as well?

```
import win32com.client
import pythoncom
import re

class Handler_Class(object):
    def OnNewMailEx(self, receivedItemsIDs):
        for ID in receivedItemsIDs.split(","):
            mail = outlook.Session.GetItemFromID(ID)
            subject = mail.Subject
            print(subject)

outlook = win32com.client.DispatchWithEvents("Outlook.Application", Handler_Class)

pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

For reference, I have two mailboxes, lets say one is `Personal` and the other is `Shared`

I would like for the script to only monitor new emails in the `Shared` inbox, but right now it only does so for my `Personal` inbox.

I have tried making the following changes to the `outlook` definition in the script to monitor the mailbox. While it didn't throw an error, it simply didn't pick up on any new mail items in that box:

```
outlook = win32com.client.DispatchWithEvents("Outlook.Application", Handler_Class).GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders.Item("Shared")
```

Does anyone know how to work around this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `NewMailEx` event is fired for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. If you want to get notifications for items from a specific account you may check out the recipient (To) and simply ignore others.

Answer (score 0):

`NewMail` / `NewMailEx` events only fires on the default Inbox folder. If you want to monitor the Inbox folder from other mailboxes, open the other account's store using either the `Namespace.Stores` collection or, if the mailbox is not shown in Outlook but you have the right to access it, `using Namespace.CreateRecipient` / `Namespace.OpenSharedDefaultFolder(recipieent, olFolderInbox)`. You can then retrieve the Inbox folder of that store using `Store.GetDefaultFolder`, and use the `Items.ItemAdd` event (where Items is returned from the `MAPIFolder.Items` property).

Comment: Can you elabroate more on your answer? I am not quite sure I understand what you mean with `Namespace.Stores`

Comment: Namespace.Stores includes all stores in the current profiles - these are the top level nodes you see in the folder tree view in Outlook. You can take a look at this objects in OutlookSpy (click Store button or click Namespace button, select Stores, click Browse)